# Code says File doesn't exist, but exists

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a file created by an OCR program which I'm trying to access after is being created. In my code I'm checking if the file exists. If I check like this:

```
 If File.Exists("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\usbtest\Portals\0\uploads\" + sNewFileName) Then
```

the program says that file doesn't exist.
However, if I set the paths like this:

```
 If File.Exists("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\usbtest\Portals\0\uploads\8application2_0001.txt") Then
```

the program proceeds.

When I debug and I step into the code line by line, then the program executes and returns that the file exists using the parameterised string (first code example)

- I have set the File/Folder permissions to Full Control to everyone (only for this test).
  The file is not read only, and 'ready for archiving'.

Any ideas?

EDITS:

I modified the code based on suggestions such as:

```
            Dim sPortalPath, sFullPath, sDirPath As String
            sDirPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\usbtest\"
            sPortalPath = "Portals\0\uploads\"
            sFullPath = sDirPath & sPortalPath & sNewFileName

            If File.Exists(sFullPath) = True Then
```

The debugger gives me the following:
[image]

When I run the program, it tells me that it doesn't exist!
(I'm pulling my hair)

Comment: Does sNewFileName really have "8application2_0001.txt" as value? Maybe you put a backslash before it.

Comment: [sigh] what does your debugger show is in the 'sNewFileName' string?  If you load the string expression into an intermediate string value and examine that, what is in there?

Comment: does `sNewFileName` contain the extension as well?

Comment: Copyed from the debugger: sNewFileName "8application2_0001.txt" String

Comment: @MartinJames How would I load the string expression into an intermediate string value and examine it

Comment: As an aside, it's always better to use '&' for string concatenation in VB, as under some circs '+' will cause the compiler to attempt to turn your string into an int (etc) and perform addition. Can't see it in this case, but it's one thing to get out of the way.

Comment: Be aware that Windows can silently change root paths for certain system locations, directing you to a shadow root in your own profile directory - this is true for things like C:\Windows and C:\ProgramData, so it wouldn't surprise me if the some was happening here.

Comment: The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault. The strings provided to the Function File.Exists are VERY likely to be not equal.

Comment: Can you try a fresh text file from notepad. Just to ensure its not the file itself

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in a string variable

```
 Dim nStr As String = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\usbtest\Portals\0\uploads\" & sNewFileName)
```

Then do your check as so...

```
If File.Exist(nStr) Then ...
```

EDIT Give this a try...

```
 Dim myFilePath as string=Server.MapPath ("~/myfolder/" & sNewFileName)
 If File.Exists(myFilePath) Then
 'do my work here'
 End If
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the if file.exist when it breaks hover over the nStr variable and make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

In VB you should concatenate strings with the `&` operator

```
If File.Exists("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\usbtest\Portals\0\uploads\" & sNewFileName) Then
```

instead of

```
If File.Exists("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\usbtest\Portals\0\uploads\" + sNewFileName) Then
```

Comment: But it works as well. Even if - you're right - it's a BAD PRACTICE.